# Ruby and Net::SFTP: why can't I move this to a separate function?

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

Writing a function that checks via SFTP if a file is present on the server.

I have written a function `sftp_file_exists_1?` that works. Now I want to split this function into two functions, and to my surprise, this does not work.

```rb
require "net/sftp"

def sftp_file_exists_1?(host, user, filename)
  Net::SFTP.start(host, user, verify_host_key: :always) do |sftp|
    sftp.stat(filename) do |response|
      return response.ok?
    end
  end
end

def sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  sftp.stat(filename) do |response|
    return response.ok?
  end
end

def sftp_file_exists_2?(host, user, filename)
  Net::SFTP.start(host, user, verify_host_key: :always) do |sftp|
    return sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  end
end

p sftp_file_exists_1?("localhost", "user", "repos")
p sftp_file_exists_2?("localhost", "user", "repos")
```

I expected:

```
true
true
```

since a file `repos` actually exists on the server. However, I get (abbreviated):

```
true
#<Net::SFTP::Request:0x000055f3b56732d0 @callback=#<Proc:0x000055f3b5673280@./test.rb:14>, ...
```

**Addendum:** this works:

```rb
def sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  begin
    sftp.stat!(filename)
  rescue Net::SFTP::StatusException
    return false
  end
  return true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem.

## Old school debugging

Let's add some `puts` to see what happens:

```
require "net/sftp"

def sftp_file_exists_1?(host, user, filename)
  Net::SFTP.start(host, user, verify_host_key: :always) do |sftp|
    puts "  BEFORE STAT"
    sftp.stat(filename) do |response|
      puts "  REQUEST FINISHED"
      return response.ok?
    end
    puts "  AFTER STAT"
  end
  puts "  NOT EXECUTED"
end

def sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  request = sftp.stat(filename) do |response|
    puts "  REQUEST FINISHED"
    return response.ok?
  end
  puts "  REQUEST SENT"
  request
end

def sftp_file_exists_2?(host, user, filename)
  Net::SFTP.start(host, user, verify_host_key: :always) do |sftp|
    puts "  CALL STAT_OK?"
    return sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  end
  puts "  NOT EXECUTED"
end
```

`sftp_file_exists_1?` outputs:

```
  BEFORE STAT
  AFTER STAT
  REQUEST FINISHED
true
```

While `sftp_file_exists_2?` outputs:

```
  CALL STAT_OK?
  REQUEST SENT
#<Net::SFTP::Request:0x0000000001db2558>
```

`"  REQUEST FINISHED"` doesn't appear.

## Async logic

The block you pass to [`stat`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/2.0.5/Net%2FSFTP%2FSession:stat) is a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). It only gets called when the server responds. To make sure the block gets executed before `sftp_stat_ok?` returns, you need to wait for the request to be complete:

```
def sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  request = sftp.stat(filename) do |response|
    return response.ok?
  end
  request.wait
end

def sftp_file_exists_2?(host, user, filename)
  Net::SFTP.start(host, user, verify_host_key: :always) do |sftp|
    return sftp_stat_ok?(sftp, filename)
  end
end
```

It isn't needed for the first version because [`start`](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-sftp/classes/Net/SFTP.html#method-c-start):

> If a block is given, it will be passed to the SFTP session and will be
>   called once the SFTP session is fully open and initialized. When the
>   block terminates, the new SSH session will automatically be closed.

Comment: Thanks. I started with Ruby yesterday and it seems I misunderstood the function/block construction. I thought the functions is called, and then the block. Now I understand that this is not true.

Comment: @LasseKliemann: This example was surprising to me too, even though I've been working with Ruby for a long time. It appears weird at first simply because it's asynchronous. A block can be executed any number of time (including 0) and at any time, depending on what the method does. Documentation helps a lot!